# How do I zip files in Xamarin for Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, zip, filestream

I have a function that creates a zip file a string array of files passed. The function does succeed in creating the zip file and the zip entry files inside it, but these zip entry files are empty. I've tried a couple of different methods - the function code below is the closest I've gotten to something working:

```
    public static bool ZipFile(string[] arrFiles, string sZipToDirectory, string sZipFileName)
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(sZipToDirectory))
        {
            FileStream fNewZipFileStream;
            ZipOutputStream zos;

            try {
                fNewZipFileStream = File.Create(sZipToDirectory + sZipFileName);
                zos = new ZipOutputStream(fNewZipFileStream);

                for (int i = 0; i < arrFiles.Length; i++) {
                    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(arrFiles[i].Substring(arrFiles[i].LastIndexOf("/") + 1));
                    zos.PutNextEntry(entry);

                    FileStream fStream = File.OpenRead(arrFiles[i]);
                    BufferedStream bfStrm = new BufferedStream(fStream);

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[bfStrm.Length];
                    int count;
                    while ((count = bfStrm.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
                        zos.Write(buffer);
                    }

                    bfStrm.Close();
                    fStream.Close();
                    zos.CloseEntry();
                }
                zos.Close();
                fNewZipFileStream.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string sErr = ex.Message;
                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                fNewZipFileStream = null;
                zos = null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I think it's got to do with the byte stream handling. I've tried this bit of code that handles the stream but it goes into an infinite loop:

```
while ((count = fStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
        zos.Write(buffer, 0, count);
}
fStream.Close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution that is quite simple - I used the ReadAllBytes method of the static File class.

```
ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(arrFiles[i].Substring(arrFiles[i].LastIndexOf("/") + 1));
zos.PutNextEntry(entry);

byte[] fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(arrFiles[i]);
zos.Write(fileContents);
zos.CloseEntry();
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `Read()` on a `FileStream` returns the amount of bytes read into the stream or 0 if the end of the stream has been reached. It will never return a value of -1.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read(v=vs.110).aspx):

`The total number of bytes read into the buffer. This might be less than the number of bytes requested if that number of bytes are not currently available, or`**`zero if the end of the stream is reached`**.

I'd modify your code to the following:

```
System.IO.FileStream fos = new System.IO.FileStream(sZipToDirectory + sZipFileName, FileMode.Create);
Java.Util.Zip.ZipOutputStream zos = new Java.Util.Zip.ZipOutputStream(fos);

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
for (int i = 0; i < arrFiles.Length; i++) {

    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo (arrFiles[i]);
    Java.IO.FileInputStream fis = new Java.IO.FileInputStream(fi.FullName);

    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(arrFiles[i].Substring(arrFiles[i].LastIndexOf("/") + 1));
    zos.PutNextEntry(entry);

    int count = 0;
    while ((count = fis.Read(buffer)) > 0) {
        zos.Write(buffer, 0, count);
    }

    fis.Close();
    zos.CloseEntry();
}
```

This is nearly identical to the code I've used for creating zip archives on Android in the past.

Comment: Matt, thank you for the reply. The fstream.Read method doesn't take just one param, so I wrote it as fStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024). I'll try this out and see if it works.

Comment: Ah, apologies for that. I used the Java.IO.FileInputStream for the file read rather than .NETs.

Comment: So `FileStream fStream = File.OpenRead(arrFiles[i])` would be `var fStream = new Java.IO.FileInputStream(arrFiles[i])`. That would allow you to use `fStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)`.

Comment: Matt, still no dice. I've tried different combinations of both FileStream fStream = File.OpenRead(arrFiles[i]) and var fStream = new Java.IO.FileInputStream(arrFiles[i]) with both fStream.Read(buffer) and fStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024). With Java.IO.FileInputStream, both fStream.Read(buffer) and fStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024) are -1, so it doesn't get to zos.Write while the old FileStream, fStream.Read(buffer) and fStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024) are both 0, so it goes into zos.Write, but goes into a (seemingly) infinite loop.

Comment: Ian, another update. I've copied the code I use for zipping verbatim minus some changes to your variable names. Let me know how you go.

Comment: Matt, thank you for following up. I got it to work using the ReadAllBytes method of the static File class. I posted the code below. Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to use [SharpZip](http://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/)? It's really easy to use.

Here is [a blog post](http://www.lihongfei.com/extract-gz-file-with-sharpzip/) I wrote to extract zip files

```
    private static void upzip(string url)
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.DownloadFile(url, "temp.zip");  
        //unzip
        ZipFile zf = null;
        try
        {
            zf = new ZipFile(File.OpenRead("temp.zip"));
            foreach (ZipEntry zipEntry in zf)
            {
                string fileName = zipEntry.Name;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                Stream zipStream = zf.GetInputStream(zipEntry);
                using (FileStream streamWriter = File.Create( fileName))
                {
                    StreamUtils.Copy(zipStream, streamWriter, buffer);
                }
            }

        }
        finally
        {
            if (zf != null)
            {
                zf.IsStreamOwner = true;
                zf.Close();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I am looking to zip files up, not unzip and also much prefer not to work with third party components or libraries. Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
private void ZipFolder(string[] _files, string zipFileName)
    {
        using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
        {
            foreach (var item in _files)
            {
                var demoFile = archive.CreateEntry(Path.GetFileName(item));
                using var readStreamW = File.OpenRead(item);
                using (var entryStream = demoFile.Open())
                {
                    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(entryStream))
                    {
                        readStreamW.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        readStreamW.CopyTo(streamWriter.BaseStream);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        using var fileStream = new FileStream(zipFileName, FileMode.Create);
        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        memoryStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
    }
```