# How can I create zip file from byte[] in Android?

Tags: xamarin.android, zip, createfile

How can I create zip file from `byte[]` in Android?
I've tried the following:

```
byte[][] result = service.ToPPC("basedata_71.zip", 71);
byte[] first = result[0];

string directory = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads).ToString();
directory += "/example.zip";
File.WriteAllBytes(directory, first);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I zip files in Xamarin for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25859020/how-do-i-zip-files-in-xamarin-for-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few options:

1.Check System.IO.Compression namespace and pick your solution

2.use Android API Java.Util.Zip.ZipFile, ZipOutputStream (check how to go from byte[] to some java Array and then to stream)

3.There are reports that SharpZipLib works

4.net standard 1.3 and System.IO.Compression.ZipFile

5.net standard 1.6 System.IO.Packaging.ZipPackage

You just need to find the API with string, byte[] or Stream and rest is really easy